# Permutations in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I can't figure out how to get permutations to return the actual permutation and not
  I tried a lot of different things to no avail.  The code I used was from itertools import permutations and then permutations([1,2,3]).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This may not be answering your question (it appears to be missing the part after 'and not'), but from your code, what you are likely seeing is the `repr` of the `itertools.permutations` iterator. You can iterate through this object just as you would a normal list in order to access all of the items. If you want to convert it to a list, you can wrap it in `list`:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> permutations([1, 2, 3])
<itertools.permutations object at 0x1e67890>
>>> list(permutations([1, 2, 3]))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

However as mentioned above, the iterator can be iterated over just like you would a normal list (the benefit of returning an iterator is that the entire sequence is not loaded into memory right away - it is instead loaded 'as needed'):

```
>>> for perm in permutations([1, 2, 3]):
...     print(perm)
... 
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Many thanks to both of you!  Apologies for the incomplete question, I intended to copy in precisely what you indicated.

Comment: @Jared No problem at all, and welcome to the site :) If either answer helped you, you can click the little check mark next to that answer's score to 'accept' it. This indicates that an answer solved your problem and essentially marks a question as complete. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.permutations` is a generator, which means you have to retrieve results from it by using it like this:

```
for permutation in itertools.permutations([1,2,3]):
   do_stuff_with(permutation)
```

or alternatively put all of them in a list:

```
list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3]))
```

or, less conveniently:

```
generator = itertools.permutations([1,2,3])
generator.__next__()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

#iteration
for p in permutations([1,2,3]):
    print(p)
```

This should work perfectly.